# Export query from Oracle through MS Access 2003 to MS Excel

Tags: excel, oracle, vba, ms-access

I need find the fastest method for exporting a query from Oracle through MS Access 2003 to MS Excel. The row count is about 34,000.

Method 1

```
CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset
```

TIME: **9 minutes**

Method 2

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO TBL_GET_ITEM_INFO FROM _GET_ITEM_INFO" 
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 8, "TBL_GET_ITEM_INFO", path, True
```

TIME: **9 minutes**

Is there a faster way?

Comment: If `_GET_ITEM_INFO` is the name of the linked table from Access' point of view, can you use just this? `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 8, "_GET_ITEM_INFO", path, True`

Comment: It is just query (_GET_ITEM_INFO ).

It does not work because access can not handle query which connect to other database (for this case its oracle DB) - maybe I read it bad?

Comment: That surprises me.  When error message do you get when you try exporting that `_GET_ITEM_INFO` query to Excel?

Comment: Object is not supported. (its type of query which connect to oracle), others queries work fine (insert, update, select just from access table) thats why I copy query to table in method 2 but this take lots of time I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped.  Since you can't export the query, I'm curious to see whether anyone else can offer a faster alternative than those two you have now.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Do it directly from Excel.  From the data tab in Excel, click "From Access," pick your database and query, and it will return the query directly into Excel.

Of course, my addendum to this would be to bypass Access entirely.  Decompose your _GET_ITEM_INFO query into actual SQL (assuming all of the data resides natively in Oracle) and run it directly in Excel, via MS Query.

Both of these methods have the added advantage of single-click refreshing of the data.